# How to get rating summary in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, review, ratings

I want the average rating of a product in Magento 2. How can I get the average or aggregate rating of product ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this

```
protected $_reviewFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
    ...
}

public function getRatingSummary()
{
    ...
    $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getEntitySummary($product, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();

    return $ratingSummary;
}
```

Or you can get **$reviewFactory** via ObjectManager *(not the best solution)*

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');

$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

**Get start based data and all over average**

```
\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $reviewCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
    \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product

    
    $result = $items = $starData = [];      
    $idArray = [2,5]; // product id
    $reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value',array("in" => $idArray))
        ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
        ->addRateVotes();
    $reviewsCollection->getSelect();

    foreach ($reviewsCollection->getItems() as $review) {

        foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote ) {
            $rating = [];
            $percent = $_vote->getPercent();
            $star = ($percent/20);
            $productId = $_vote->getEntityPkValue();
            
            $productModel = $this->_product->create();
            $product = $productModel->load($productId);             
            $countReview = $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getTotalReviews($productId,false);
            $review_id = $_vote->getReviewId();
            
            $rating['review_id'] = $review_id;
            $rating['product_id'] = $productId;     
            $rating['percent']   = $percent;
            $rating['star']      = $star;
            $rating['nickname']  = $review->getNickname();                  
            $items[] = $rating;
            $starData[$star][] = $rating;
        }
        
    }
    
    if(count($items) > 0)   {           
        $result['all'] = $items;
        $result['star'] = $starData;            
        
        if(isset($starData[1]))
            $result ['count'][1] = count($starData[1]);
        else
            $result ['count'][1] = 0;
            
        if(isset($starData[2]))
            $result ['count'][2] = count($starData[2]);
        else
            $result ['count'][2] = 0;
            
        if(isset($starData[3]))
            $result ['count'][3] = count($starData[3]);
        else
            $result ['count'][3] = 0;
            
        if(isset($starData[4]))
            $result ['count'][4] = count($starData[4]);
        else
            $result ['count'][4] = 0;
        
        if(isset($starData[5]))
            $result ['count'][5] = count($starData[5]);
        else
            $result ['count'][5] = 0;
        
        $sum = $startSum = 0;
        
        foreach($result['count'] as $number => $count) {
            $sum += $number * $count;
            $startSum +=  $count;   
        }
        
        $avg =  $sum/$startSum;
        
        $result ['count']['all'] = count($result['all']);
        $result ['count']['avg'] = round($avg,1);
    }
    
    return $result;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out `->addRateVotes()` . You just saved the day!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);
$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
?>
<div class="rating-summary item" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" >
    <div class="rating-result" title="<?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%">
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="100">
        <span style="width:<?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%">
            <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php echo $ratingSummary; ?>%</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1 - I used like reference this file:**

```
app/design/frontend/PATH/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

**2 - Find this line:**

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
```

**3 - Paste this lines after:**

```
$review_model->getEntitySummary($_product);
$reviewRating = (int) $_product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();

// Show the value
var_dump($reviewRating);
```

Comment: How to get the rating stars in my custom product scroller ?