# How to get ratings in a group count of 5 star, 4 star, 3 star, 2 star and 1 star. [Magento 2]

Tags: magento2

How to get ratings in a group count of 5 star, 4 star, 3 star, 2 star and 1 star in Magento 2.0 in form.phtml of Magento_Review template.[image]

Comment: I don't think that you can do it with 3 attributes for rating. You will need to use only 1 rating criteria first (Right now in default magento there are price, quality and value, so total rating is average of 3 criteria, which can be decimal).

Comment: Yes I am using only 1 for rating. But how we call Rating Summery in Magento 2 on rating form page.

Comment: Have you got solution for this Question?

Comment: @RonakChauhan, Yes I create custom function and query for this.

Comment: can you give me that code?

Comment: @RonakChauhan, Posted that method in your question. Check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create and call this method with your product ID. Also make sure you have only 1 rating option in admin.

```
public function getAllStart($pid) {
    $review = $this->_objectReview->getCollection()     //\Magento\Review\Model\Review $reviewFactory (_objectReview)
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status_id', 1)
            ->addEntityFilter('product', $pid)          //$pid = > your current product ID
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->addFieldToSelect('review_id')
    ;
    $review->getSelect()->columns('detail.detail_id')->joinInner(
            ['vote' => $review->getTable('rating_option_vote')], 'main_table.review_id = vote.review_id', array('review_value' => 'vote.value')
    );
    $review->getSelect()->order('review_value DESC');
    $review->getSelect()->columns('count(vote.vote_id) as total_vote')->group('review_value');
    for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--) {
        $arrRatings[$i]['value'] = 0;
    }
    foreach ($review as $_result) {
        $arrRatings[$_result['review_value']]['value'] = $_result['total_vote'];
    }
    return $arrRatings;
    }
```

Comment: it's not working if the site have multiple criterias ratings.

Comment: admin rating change after display Error frontend "Item (Magento\Review\Model\Review) with the same ID "364" already exists."

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to get a rating summary of all of the ratings in 1.

If that is the case you simply need to call the ratings summary template.

Check out this question:

[How to get rating summary in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123568/how-to-get-rating-summary-in-magento-2)